# Why do I get the Package caption Warning?

Tags: captions, packages, document-classes, warnings

While compiling my document, I get the following warning:

```
Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package), standard defaults will be used. See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

However, this is what my document looks like:

```
\documentclass[sn-basic]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{natbib, caption}
\jyear{2022}%
\begin{document}
    <TEXT>
\end{document}
```

And I have two other files; `sn-basic.bst` and `sn-jnl.cls`.

Why do I get this warning? And what can I do to overcome it?

Comment: Because you are using an (to `caption`) unknown class that have changed the caption setup. In order for `caption` to do its stuff it will then first reset the caption setup to that of the standard classes, and then make its changes. This might not be what one want.

Comment: a warning is not an error.

Comment: i'm dealing with the exact same error. i'm using sn-jnl as well. after some research, i came to know that sn-jnl is a faulty class with many errors. Probably, some overlapping of required packages is causing this error. can't find the solution to it.